# Xcode 10 - Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9.0 [12] error

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, storyboard, safearealayoutguide

I am trying to compile an application with a Deployment Target iOS 8.0 on Xcode 10 using an iOS 8.3 simulator.

I have already disabled Safe Area Layout Guide from the Storyboard, but the issue still exists.

[image: Safe Area Layout Guide is disabled]

Do you know how to help me?

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure you `disable Safe Area Layout Guide from launch screen and storyboard`.
2. Set `builds for -> deployment target 8.1` in interface builder document.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about disabling it also from the launch screen :)

Comment: Thank you - it was pointing to Main.storyboard so without your help I don't know if I would ever check storyboard file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using storyboards make sure to update the deployment target:

[image: Builds for]